# Vague Errors from VIP Scanner Plugin

Tags: child-theme

I am building a site with WordPress 3.4.2, have made a child theme of WooTheme's Canvas 5 (http://www.woothemes.com/2012/06/canvas/) and am now using the VIP Scanner plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vip-scanner/).

I managed to resolve the majority of the errors outputted for my child theme, but one or two of them are vaguely worded and I cannot figure out a way to solve them:

1. Warning: Possible output of restricted variables
2. Warning: Attribution link missing or not well formatted

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first one says that you're doing an echo or print of one of $GLOBALS, $_SERVER, $_GET, $_REQUEST, or $_POST. This can often lead to Cross-Site-Scripting security issues. It should tell you what line the offending code is on.

The second one says that you're missing the WordPress.com VIP link, which is a link to http://en.wordpress.com/vip-hosting that shows up on VIP sites.